# Java "Null Pointer Exception" - responseEntity.getBody().isNull()

Tags: java, resttemplate

```
    ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = null;

    //Calling POST Method
    response=restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request,JsonNode.class);
    restResponse.setStatusCode(response.getStatusCode());
    restResponse.setHeaders(response.getHeaders());
    if(response.getBody().isNull())
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
```

**Issue: Facing Null Pointer Exception**

Eventhough I am trying to handle Not Null scenario using check `response.getBody().isNull()` , but seems like this check also leads to null pointer exeception.

My assumptions : `response.getBody()` should return me JsonNode object on which I am trying to execute `isNull()` method.
I am not sure how this call again lead to Null Pointer Exception.
On Intellij It shows as `getBody()` method is `@Nullable` there are chances of Null pointer exception.

I searched online some solution says to use `response.getBody()!=null` will work. I am confused. Then what is use of `isNull()` method?

Comment: Have you checked if `response` is `null` directly after `response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,request,JsonNode.class);`?

Comment: What does the javadoc for `isNull()` say?

Comment: If `response.getBody()` returns `null`, then calling any method on it, including `isNull()`, will cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Isn't `isNull()` checking if Value is null, and `!= null` check if reference to object is null?

Comment: See also: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Jesper : I though response.getBody() will return JsonNode object with value as null.  `@Nullable
    public T getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }`

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`HttpEntity#hasBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#hasBody--) before retrieving the body. There is a good chance the entity doesn't have a body. It's more expressive than a `response.getBody() != null` check.

Please, don't assume that `isNull()` on an object would check that object on null. `this == null` is fundamentally wrong and never true.

```
class Body {
    public boolean isNull() {
        return this == null; // never makes sense
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `isNull()` method does not check whether the `body` field is null, it checks wether it was created from a NULL value.

From the Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Method that can be used to check if this node was created from
 * JSON literal null value.
 */
```

Its confusingly named, but remember: You cannot call a method on nothing (hence the NullPointerException). The answer you found earlier is true, to verify if that object is null itself, you need to work with a `!= null` check.